# How do I search for a wildcard character in Microsoft CRM 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I need to search for accounts in Microsoft CRM, using a wildcard search to get a "contains" search for the user's input. So if the user enters "ABC", I use ConditionOperator.Like and the value "%ABC%".

My question is, how would I search for a customer name that contains a percentage sign, such as "100% Great llc"? I can't find a way to escape the %.

Comment: What version of MS CRM you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [square blocks](http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html) for special characters, for instance like `[%]`. So the condition would be: `100[%] Great llc` or `%100[%] Great llc%`.

**--EDIT--**

This is in response to your comment.

Try utilizing the [`ConditionExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151203.aspx), something like following:

```
//1. Condition expression.
ConditionExpression nameCondition= new ConditionExpression();
            nameCondition.AttributeName = "AccountName";
            nameCondition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Like;
            nameCondition.Values = new string[] { "%100[%] Great llc%" };

//2. Create filter expression
FilterExpression nameFilter = new FilterExpression();
nameFilter.Conditions = new ConditionExpression[] { nameCondition };

//3. Provide columns
ColumnSet resultSetColumns = new ColumnSet();
            resultSetColumns.Attributes = new string[] { "name", "address" };

//4. Prepare query expression
QueryExpression qryExpression = new QueryExpression();
            qryExpression.Criteria = nameFilter;
            qryExpression.ColumnSet = resultSetColumns;

//5. Set the table to query.
qryExpression.EntityName = EntityName.account.ToString();

//6. BusinessEntityCollection accountsResultSet = service.RetrieveMultiple(qryExpression);
```

Though I have played alot with CRM, but never came across special characters scenario. Let me know your findings. [This article](http://wdeconinck.wordpress.com/tag/crm-40/) has some revelations.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It doesn't return accounts containing a %.

Comment: @Geoff: Did you try tsql? For instance, try `'%100\%%' ESCAPE '\'?` or `'%100\% Great llc%' ESCAPE '\'?`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Coding standards force me to use the CRM SDK and no direct SQL access :(

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a SQL-based approach so I'm not sure if this helps.

One way I know is through the user interface with an asterisk *

So if you want to find all of the accounts that have a % sign just type in *% into the account search.